# When I create contract using another contract how could I access his methods in web3js?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, dapp-development, solidity-0.5.x

Hey I have file 'contractFactory.sol' inside this file I have

```
contract contractFactory{

    event contractCreated(string name, address institution, address parent);

    function createContract(
        string _name,
        address head,
        address creator,
        address[] _Members)
    public returns(address){

        Contracts  ContractAddress = new Contracts(_name , head , creator , _Members);
        emit contractCreated(_name,address(ContractAddress), creator);
        return address(ContractAddress);
    }
}

contract Contracts{

    function  dosomthing(){}
}
```

Now in front-end web3js, I had create 'Contracts' contract using 'contractsFactory'.Does any one know how I could access dosomting() methods in web3js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example which relies on web3.js v1.0.0-beta.34.

Please note that I had to fix various compilation errors in your contracts, so it is not entirely compatible with your (non-working) code, yet should suffice for you to get started.

On top of that, please note that I have also declared `address institution` as `indexed`, in order to make the extraction of this data from the receipt of executing function `createContract` easier.

**Your altered code:**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract ContractInstance {
    string public _name;
    address public _head;
    address public _creator;

    constructor(string name, address head, address creator) public {
        _name = name;
        _head = head;
        _creator = creator;
    }

    function doSomething(string name) public {
        _name = name;
    }
}

contract ContractFactory {
    event ContractCreated(string name, address indexed institution, address parent);

    function createContract(string name, address head, address creator) public returns (address) {
        ContractInstance contractInstance = new ContractInstance(name, head, creator);
        emit ContractCreated(name, address(contractInstance), creator);
        return address(contractInstance);
    }
}
```

**Web3.js script:**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545");

const YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001";
const YOUR_ARTIFACTS_PATH = "C:/Your/Artifacts/Path/";

const ARG2 = "0x1234567812345678123456781234567812345678";
const ARG3 = "0x8765432187654321876543218765432187654321";

async function deploy(contractName, contractArgs) {
    const abi = fs.readFileSync(YOUR_ARTIFACTS_PATH + contractName + ".abi");
    const bin = fs.readFileSync(YOUR_ARTIFACTS_PATH + contractName + ".bin");
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    const options = {data: "0x" + bin, arguments: contractArgs};
    const transaction = contract.deploy(options);
    const handle = await send(transaction);
    const args = transaction.encodeABI().slice(options.data.length);
    return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), handle.contractAddress);
}

function deployed(contractName, contractAddr) {
    const abi = fs.readFileSync(YOUR_ARTIFACTS_PATH + contractName + ".abi");
    return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), contractAddr);
}

async function send(transaction) {
    const options = {
        to   : transaction._parent._address,
        data : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas  : (await web3.eth.getBlock("latest")).gasLimit
    };
    const signedTransaction  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY);
    const transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
    return transactionReceipt;
}

async function run() {
    const contractFactory  = await deploy("ContractFactory", []);
    const receipt1         = await send(contractFactory.methods.createContract("MyName", ARG2, ARG3));
    const contractAddress  = "0x" + receipt1.logs[0].topics[1].slice(-40);
    const contractInstance = deployed("ContractInstance", contractAddress);
    const oldName          = await contractInstance.methods._name().call();
    const receipt2         = await send(contractInstance.methods.doSomething("YourName"));
    const newName          = await contractInstance.methods._name().call();
    console.log("oldName:", oldName);
    console.log("newName:", newName);
}

run();
```